# Reactjs - How to use redux in Stripe checkout form

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react stripe in my project. I followd the tutorial https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react.

As mentioned in the document, the form is exported as follows.

```
export default injectStripe(Form)
```

In the documentation the api call is made as follows.

```
async submit(ev) {
  let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
  let response = await fetch("/charge", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
    body: token.id
  });

  if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")
}
```

But i need to connect the redux for making the submit api call.

checkoutActions.js

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
export function checkout(obj) {
  const api = types.API_URL_CHECKOUT;
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
      type: types.ACTION_CHECKOUT,
      promise: client => client.post(api, obj).then((data) => {
        return data;
      }),
    });
  };
}
```

So i have modified the form export as follows.

```
export default connect(state => ({
  ...state.resp
}),{
  ...checkoutActions
})injectStripe(Form)
```

But it is returning the error

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Any idea on how to connect redux in stripe checkout form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis over injectStripe.

```
export default connect(state => ({...state.resp}),{...checkoutActions })(injectStripe(Form))
```